# Rules Hole in Shobu

Tags: shobu

In the board game "Shobu," there are a few scenarios not covered by the rules.

1. There is no rule that stops players from recreating the same board state turn after turn (such as the rule in chess that creates a game draw after 3 repetitions)
2. Nothing is mentioned on what to do if you **cannot** make a move at all, which can happen multiple ways.

I have chosen not to make 2 separate questions for this because I believe that I can ask one single question to get my answers, that being:

**Is there another definitive rules resource for Shobu that covers these scenarios? Or is there no such ruling, and I must make a house ruling?**

Comment: what situation would cause you not to be able to make a move at all?

Comment: 2 situations that I can think of off the top of my head (I don't have a board in front of me unfortuanately) are 
First, a passive move on both homeboards is blocked by being "Cornered" (this situation is less relevant because it would be difficult to not lose next turn anyway, although I suppose it's possible for your opponent's homeboards to be locked similarly, causing a total game lock). Second, your homeboards each have only one piece in the bottom right, and the other 2 boards you have only 1 piece in the top left. No possible passive move can be matched with an aggressive move.

Comment: My apologies on my comment, I messed up my explanation. The second option would only be if you have the 4 boards with all the corners taken, so left homeboard one piece in bottom left, right homeboard one piece in bottom right, and mirrored onto the top corners for the opposing homeboards.

Comment: related thread on BBG: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2224335/no-valid-passive-move

Answer (score 4):

1. No repetition rule exists. You are free to repeat the position as many times as you like.
2. You lose if you cannot make a legal move.

I messaged Manolis Vranas, the designer, on Facebook, and he says:

> If you cannot make both parts of a valid move (Passive & Aggressive) then you lose the match.
>   At the later stages of a game, board management can become very important, so you don't paint yourself into a corner.

As for the question "is there a rule regarding repetition?", he says:

> Not in so many words, no. Since active play happens on all 4 boards - and the Passive part of each player's move must originate on their Home boards - you don't tend to see the back-and-forth repetition that you get in a game like Chess.